# Allow terminal that spawned rdesktop to close without closing rdesktop window in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, rdesktop

Running Ubuntu 9.10, when I execute:

```
rdesktop 147.145.168.224 &
```

The remote desktop window appears, and the command appears to end in the shell it was executed from because I can execute further commands; however, when I close the shell the remote desktop window closes with it.  How can I spawn the rdesktop process such that it remains open when the terminal that spawned it closes?  I don't seem to have the same problem with running:

```
firefox &
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use:

```
nohup rdesktop 147.145.168.224 &
```

Comment: nice, wasn't aware of this nohup command... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a background process running already and want to close it's parent process (the terminal window) without killing the child process, you can `disown` it:

```
$ rdesktop 147.145.168.224 &
$ disown
```

After the process is disowned, it will not be killed when it's parent process terminates.

As a side note, you don't have this problem with firefox, because `firefox` is a shell script that launches `firefox-bin`, such that `firefox-bin` is not a child process of your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just launch your rdesktop from your launcher. For default Ubuntu just hit:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

and then enter your command in the the entry box:

```
rdesktop 147.145.168.224 &
```

Although I don't use the ampersand (&) for mine.  Typically my command is:

```
rdesktop -u myUname -fP 10.130.3.13
```

This opens rdesktop in fullscreen mode and enables bitmap caching. To get back to my desktop I just have to hit:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

And then the same combo to get back into fullscreen.